# How do I get mocha to run "exports"-style tests on Windows?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, expresso

I have NodeJS and Mocha installed and working on Windows 7 x64 - so far, so good - but I can't get Mocha to recognise any tests defined using the `exports` interface (as described at http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)

If I create test/bdd.js containing the following code:

```
var should = require('should');

describe('TestDemo - BDD interface', function(){
  describe('#foo', function(){
    it('1 should equal 1', function(){ (1).should.equal(1);  });
  });
});
```

I can run mocha and get the expected output:

```
D:\Projects\NodeDemo>mocha -R spec

  TestDemo - BDD interface
    #foo
      ✓ 1 should equal 1

  ✔ 1 tests complete (7ms)

D:\Projects\NodeDemo>
```

BUT if I create test/exports.js containing this code (based on the 'exports' interface example provided on the Mocha site)

```
var should = require('should');

module.exports = {
  'TestDemo - exports interface': {
    '#foo': {
      '1 should equal 1': function(){ (1).should.equal(1); }
    }
  }
};
```

when I run Mocha it doesn't find any tests:

> D:\Projects\NodeDemo>mocha -R spec
>
> ✔ 0 tests complete (1ms)
>
> D:\Projects\NodeDemo>

I suspect I've either missed a switch or something for specifying which interface `mocha` should be using for test definitions, or I've found something that isn't supported on Windows (yet). Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course, the second you post it to StackOverflow you notice a line of documentation that I'd swear wasn't there before... :)

```
mocha(1)

Usage: mocha [options] [files]

Options:

-u, --ui <name>        specify user-interface (bdd|tdd|exports)
```

and sure enough, running

```
D:\Projects\NodeDemo>mocha -ui exports -R spec
```

does exactly what I expected. D'OH.

Comment: Glad it wasn't just me... :)